# Sum multiple rows and display the sum value in next column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I like to do the below operation:

```
Sale ID     Q1   Q2              Total           Net Amount
530095243   0    12,600.00       12,600.00       17,657.17 
530095243   0    5,057.00        5,057.00        17,657.17 
530095243   0    (51,857.30)     (51,857.30)     17,657.17 
530095243   0    (51,567.60)     (51,567.60)     17,657.17 
530095243   0    51,567.60       51,567.60       17,657.17 
530095243   0    51,857.47       51,857.47       17,657.17
```

The Net amount column has the sum of total.... In my case I like to show the sum in the last row which would like as below:

```
Sale ID     Q1   Q2              Total           Net Amount
530095243   0    12,600.00       12,600.00       0
530095243   0    5,057.00        5,057.00        0 
530095243   0    (51,857.30)     (51,857.30)     0 
530095243   0    (51,567.60)     (51,567.60)     0
530095243   0    51,567.60       51,567.60       0 
530095243   0    51,857.47       51,857.47       17,657.17
```

Comment: This can be done quite easy with a subquery. But seriously, why do you want to do this? I see no sense in this.

Comment: What determines the "last row", ordered by what?

Comment: Instead of showing the total in the last row, can you show it in the row "after" the last row? In this case, you would use a ROLLUP clause.

Comment: If this is for an application such as .net, coldfusion, java, whatever, it would probably be simpler to do this with your application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
        Sale_ID BIGINT 
      , Q1 INT              
      , Q2 DECIMAL(10,2)     
      , Total DECIMAL(10,2)
      , Net_Amount DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Sale_ID, Q1, Q2, Total, Net_Amount)
VALUES 
    (530095243,   0,    12600.00,   12600.00, 17657.17), 
    (530095243,   0,    5057.00,    5057.00,  17657.17), 
    (530095243,   0,    51857.30,   51857.30, 17657.17), 
    (530095243,   0,    51567.60,   51567.60, 17657.17), 
    (530095243,   0,    51567.60,   51567.60, 17657.17), 
    (530095243,   0,    51857.47,   51857.47, 17657.17),
    (530095244,   0,    12600.00,   12600.00, 17657.17), 
    (530095244,   0,    5057.00,    5057.00,  17657.17), 
    (530095244,   0,    51857.47,   51857.47, 17657.17)  

DECLARE @new_table TABLE
(
        Sale_ID BIGINT 
      , Q1 INT              
      , Q2 DECIMAL(10,2)     
      , Total DECIMAL(10,2)
      , Net_Amount DECIMAL(10,2)
)

;WITH t AS 
(
    SELECT  
          Sale_ID
        , Q1
        , Q2
        , Total
        , Net_Amount
        , RNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Sale_ID ORDER BY Sale_ID, Q1, Q2, Total, Net_Amount)
    FROM @temp
),
mx AS 
(
    SELECT 
          LRow = MAX(RNum)
        , Sale_ID
    FROM t
    GROUP BY Sale_ID
)
INSERT INTO @new_table (Sale_ID, Q1, Q2, Total, Net_Amount)
SELECT  t.Sale_ID
    ,   t.Q1
    ,   t.Q2
    ,   t.Total
    ,   Net_Amount = CASE WHEN mx.LRow = t.RNum THEN t.Net_Amount ELSE 0 END
FROM t t
JOIN mx ON t.Sale_ID = mx.Sale_ID

SELECT * 
FROM @new_table
```

Comment: The above will not work if you few more different Sale_ID. I need to sum the total based on the sale id

Comment: Hi Devart.. how can i insert this output in to a table

Answer (score 0):

why you want to do this ! I think there are no any sense to do this .

I want to update you that you should store only raw data into database any operational data is not good to store e.g. total, percentage, average etc.

This kind of operational data you can easily populate at your application end using stored raw data.

I would like to request here please remove this kind of operational field and make your records and set more dynamic .

I hope you clear with this.

Thanks...!

Comment: The output of the query will be generated as xls report.... so nothing to do with application level...

Comment: ok here I would like give more one suggestion . once your report generate in xls file after that you can easily add last column for total and that total you can calculate using excel inbuilt sum function .